# Get cell address of index position

Tags: excel, vba, indexing

I am trying to get the cell address of the index position. Using the code below, i have that position but when i try and get the address, i doesn't work.

```
Sub IndexAndMatch()

DeclareVarsHrsRole

Dim k As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim y As Integer

For i = 1 To AwardTBL.ListRows.Count
   If AwardTBL.ListColumns("Home").DataBodyRange(i) = Range("SelectedCareHome") Then
           For k = AwardTBL.ListColumns("NVQ qualification").Index To AwardTBL.ListColumns("Care 
           Supplement (GC only)").Index
             For y = Table17.ListColumns("NVQ qualification").Index To Table17.ListColumns("Care 
             Supplement (GC only)").Index
                 If AwardTBL.ListColumns(y) = Table17.ListColumns(k) Then
                  Range(Table17.ListColumns(k)).Address
                 End If
             Next y
           Next k
    End If
 Next i
End Sub
```

Any Ideas.

Thanks

Comment: What result to you get from `Range(Table17.ListColumns(k)).Address`?

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean? is it throwing an error? if so, which line and with what message?

Comment: Sorry, I get a 'Invalid use of property' message on line Range(Table17.ListColumns(k)).Address

Comment: try with `MsgBox Table17.ListColumns(k).Range.Address` (see [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listcolumn.range))

Comment: And what does `Range(Table17.ListColumns(k))` return?

Comment: Thanks @HTH, i get the range of cell addresses in that column. What if i just need the address of the header for the column. Sorry, should have made it clearer in the question, heads fuzzy

Comment: Think i got it with Offset `msgbox Table17.ListColumns(k).Range.Cells(k).Offset(-1, 0)`

Comment: since `Range` property _"Returns a Range object that represents the range to which the specified list object applies."_ , than you can _treat_ it as such: see [MS Range documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object))

Comment: The header cell is `Table17.ListColumns(k).Range.Cells(1).Address` or `Table17.Range.Cells(1, k).Address`.

Comment: You can also get header range using `Table17.HeaderRowRange(k).Address`, the data for column using `Table17.ListColumns(k).DataBodyRange.Address` or the whole column using `Table17.ListColumns(4).Range.Address`

Comment: Why do you want just the address of the cell? I'm guessing it's because you then want to reference that address later on - I'd suggest using the actual reference to the cell rather than just the address.